# grouped box plots are too narrow to read

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

Actually everything works just fine: I try to compare different groups in my survey in one chart. thus I wrote the following code in Python (Jupyter-Notebook)

```
for value in values:
    catpool=getcat()
    py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
    data = []
    for cata in catpool:
        for con in constraints:
            data.append(  go.Box( y=getdf(value,cata,con[0])['Y'+value],x=con[1], name=cata, showlegend=False, boxmean='sd',
                             #boxpoints='all',
                             jitter=0.3,
                             pointpos=0 ) )
    layout=go.Layout(title="categorie: "+getclearname(value)+" - local space syntax measurements on placements<br>",yaxis=dict( title='percentage of range between flat extremes'),boxmode='group',showlegend=True)
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.offline.iplot(fig, filename='pandas-box-plot')
```

the function 'getdf' queries a column from a database

unfortunately it results in an unreadable diagram like this
[a diagram with to narrow box plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEvfD.png)
is it possible to give the groups less spacing and accordingly the boxplots in the group more? Or anything else that would make it more readable?

Thank you

Comment: Can you fix indentation in the question?

Comment: @titipata done... thx

Comment: Also in the answer :) Sorry for bugging, lol!

Comment: @titipata also done - confusing^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem at my own:
The strange behaviour occured, because of the `for cata in catpool` loop - data for boxplots in groups has to contain the group value in the data frame: so I just didn't loop at this place, but looped in the concatenation of the SQL-statement. So the same queries were carried out, but were joined together by "UNION" like this:

```
def formstmtelse (val, category, ext, constraint, nine=True):
    stmt=""
    if nine:
        matrix=['11','12','13','21','22','23','31','32','33']
    else:
        matrix=['11'] 
    j=0
    for cin in category:
        j=j+1
        if j>1:
            stmt=stmt+" UNION "
        m=0
        for cell in matrix:
            m=m+1
            if m>1:
                stmt=stmt+"""UNION 
                """
            stmt=stmt+"""SELECT '"""+cin+"""' AS cata,
            """
            if ext:
                stmt=stmt+"""((("""+val+"""-MIN"""+val+""")/(MAX"""+val+"""-MIN"""+val+"""))*100) AS Y"""+val
            else:
                stmt=stmt+"""((("""+val+""")/(MAX"""+val+"""))*100) AS Y"""+val
            stmt=stmt+""" 
            FROM `stests` 
            JOIN ssubject 
            ON ssubject.ssubjectID=stests.ssubjectID 
            JOIN scountries
            ON CountryGrownUpIn=scountriesID
            JOIN scontinents
            ON Continent=scontinentsID
            JOIN gridpoint 
            ON stests.FlatID=gridpoint.GFlatID AND G"""+cin+cell+"""=GIntID 
            JOIN 
            (
                SELECT GFlatID AS GSUBFlatID"""
            stmt=stmt+""",
            MAX("""+val+""") AS MAX"""+val+""",MIN("""+val+""") AS MIN"""+val
            stmt=stmt+"""
                FROM gridpoint 
                GROUP BY GSUBFlatID
            )
            AS virtualtable 
            ON FlatID=virtualtable.GSUBFlatID 
            """+constraint+" "
    return stmt
```

that solves the problem. The 'x' attribute of the box call must be a list or dataframe, not just a single string, even though the string is always the same. I guess this was causing 'invisible' x-values making the automated scaling impossible, or in other words a new point in the legend for each query with a new constraint and for each category, only one dataframe is needed for every constraint. when changing this - fine adjustments could be made by adding boxgroupgap or groupgab attribute to layout...
please excuse my english